# How do i get unity to wait until my animation is done

Tags: unity-game-engine, delay, yield, coroutine, ienumerator

I'm working on a unity project and I want too switch between scenes with an fade in and fade out animation.
The animation are done and I can access them but I'm working with yield and Ienumerator functions from a tutorial but I can't get it to work.

```
//from my animation script
public IEnumerator fadeIn()
{
    isFading = true;
    animator.SetTrigger("FadeIn");
    while (isFading)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    }
}

// from my main menu script.
public void btnPlay()
{
    StartCoroutine(fadeIn());
    Debug.Log("AfterIn");
    SceneManager.LoadScene("playOptions");
    StartCoroutine(fadeOut());
    Debug.Log("AfterOut");
}

IEnumerator fadeIn()
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(animatorscript.fadeIn());
}
IEnumerator fadeOut()
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(animatorscript.fadeOut());
}
```

I've updated my question. But when I run it i see no animation. It goos direct to the next scene and de debug messages direct after each other.

Comment: Your title does not match your question - what do you want Unity to wait for? The fade out animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to start a Coroutine you need to call it like this `StartCoroutine(fadeIn)` the same way you are doing `yield return StartCoroutine(animatorscript.fadeIn())`.

So you need to append

```
public void btnPlay()
{
    StartCoroutine(fadeIn);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("playOptions");
    StartCoroutine(fadeOut);
}
```

See [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) for more information on `StartCoroutine`

UPDATE: In regards to your updated question, I assume you wish to wait until the fadein finishes to load the scene.

Something like this would do the trick;

```
public void btnPlay()
{
    StartCoroutine(SceneFadeAndLoad);
}

IEnumerator SceneFadeAndLoad()
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(fadeIn);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("playOptions");
    yield return StartCoroutine(fadeOut);
}
```

Comment: Also don't forget the `using System.Collections;` statement when using coroutines

Comment: It still doesn't work,

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: and "using System.Collections;" am I using allready

Comment: I have updated my answer with regards to your question

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot